# How to get an url in a string with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regex to get an url but i miss the end of the url
here is an example of string containing an url

```
<div class=\"ExternalClassC7001553FFC442DD9B99547999723C7B\">http://bazar.flow.be/Knowledge/Legal/FR/Ina/Circul/Circul BB adm. 2014/circ_bb_p_2014_xxx.doc</div>
```

I've to get this in output:

```
http://bazar.flow.be/Knowledge/Legal/FR/Ina/Circul/Circul BB adm. 2014/circ_bb_p_2014_xxx.doc
```

For now, i use this regex that return me: "http://bazar.flow.be/Knowledge/Legal/FR/Ina/Circul/Circul"

```
@"((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\._~%]*)*"
```

thanks for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\._~%]*)*([^<]+)*
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/83

Comment: it won't work here http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/82 `(\s\S+)*` will consume all the following characters.

Comment: adding this `[^<>]*` after the last also works. A simple solution is adding space inside the last character class..

Answer (score 1):

include a space in between somewhere:

```
@"((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\. _~%]*)*"

                                                                               |
                                                                          added space here
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add space in last character class, and you can simplify your regex to:

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)\://|www\.)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?:/[\w?&=;+!'()*.~% -]*)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a backslash and a space at the end of your regex:

```
@"((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\._~%\ ]*)*"
```